# Can't establish connection between openvpn client and server

Tags: openvpn, port-forwarding

I've set up an openvpn server on a computer and I'm currently trying to connect to it with a client. The server seems to init correctly (although it does give a warning about the common 192.168.1.X subnet). When running the client I get a failed TLS key negotiation though, asking me to check network connectivity. I have made sure that the gateway is set up to forward UDP traffic to the correct IP/port, which seems to be the most common problem in this case.

The client machine used for testing the connection is on the same LAN (and subnet) as the server if this makes any difference.

Output from server init:

> Tue Dec 08 14:17:05 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.8 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO]
>   [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Aug  4 2015
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:05 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015, LZO 2.08
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:05 2015 NOTE: your local LAN uses the extremely common subnet a
>   ddress 192.168.0.x or 192.168.1.x.  Be aware that this might create routing conf
>   licts if you connect to the VPN server from public locations such as internet ca
>   fes that use the same subnet.
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:05 2015 Diffie-Hellman initialized with 2048 bit key
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:05 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:05 2015 do_ifconfig, tt->ipv6=0, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:05 2015 open_tun, tt->ipv6=0
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:05 2015 TAP-WIN32 device [Ethernet 2] opened: \.\Global{77EC3
>   BE0-AE52-47D2-94D3-88E50868D948}.tap
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:05 2015 TAP-Windows Driver Version 9.21
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:05 2015 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of
>    10.8.0.1/255.255.255.252 on interface {77EC3BE0-AE52-47D2-94D3-88E50868D948} [D
>   HCP-serv: 10.8.0.2, lease-time: 31536000]
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:05 2015 Sleeping for 10 seconds...
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 Successful ARP Flush on interface [26] {77EC3BE0-AE52-4
>   7D2-94D3-88E50868D948}
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 10.8.0.0 MASK 255.255
>   .255.0 10.8.0.2
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 ROUTE: route addition failed using CreateIpForwardEntry
>   : The object already exists.   [status=5010 if_index=26]
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 Route addition via IPAPI failed [adaptive]
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 Route addition fallback to route.exe
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 env_block: add PATH=C:\Windows\System32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\W
>   INDOWS\System32\Wbem
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 UDPv4 link local (bound): [undef]
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [undef]
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 IFCONFIG POOL: base=10.8.0.4 size=62, ipv6=0
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:17:15 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed

Output from client init (edited out the host IP):

> Tue Dec 08 14:19:52 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.8 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Aug  4 2015
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:19:52 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015, LZO 2.08
>
> Enter Private Key Password:
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:19:56 2015 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:19:56 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:19:56 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:19:56 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]*HOST IP*:*PORT*
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:20:56 2015 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:20:56 2015 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:20:56 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
>
> Tue Dec 08 14:20:56 2015 Restart pause, 2 second(s)

Comment: Is there a firewall rule to allow the udp traffic in to the server?

Comment: There was not apparently, added a rule for inbound UDP traffic to the port in question and now I have successfully established a connection. Thank you! Please leave an answer and I will mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check to make sure that there is a firewall rule on the server to allow the correct UDP traffic in.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your server's config (f.e. /etc/openvpn/server.conf) doesn't use the same subnet as your physical network. Try using something unusual like:

```
server 192.168.123.1 255.255.255.0
ifconfig 192.168.123.1 192.168.123.2
```